# How to logout a user before sending a user a verification email in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

When creating a new user, I need to log them out and then send a verification email to ensure that they own the email address. Currently my code creates the user and executes the "sendEmailVerification" call but keeps the user logged in. How can I log my user out and check that they have verified their email?

```
func signUp(with email: String, password: String, firstName: String, lastName: String) {
    self.presentActivityView()
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) {[unowned self] (user, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
            self.dismissActivityView()
            if let err = error {
                self.addAlertController(title: "Error!", message: err.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                let changeReq = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
                changeReq?.displayName = firstName + " " + lastName
                if let url = self.profilePicURLString {
                    changeReq?.photoURL = URL(string: url)
                }
                changeReq?.commitChanges(completion: { (error) in
                    if error == nil {
                        //Profile updated successfully
                    }else {
                        //Profile not updated successfully
                    }
                })
                Auth.auth().currentUser?.sendEmailVerification(completion: { (error) in
                    if error == nil {
                        //Verification initiated successfully
                    }else {
                        print("Error: \(error)")
                    }
                })
                let vc = MainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SNStoryFeedController") as! SNStoryFeedController
                let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
                UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = nc
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you need to sign out the user?  That's not normally part of the workflow involved.

Comment: @DougStevenson - I only want the user to be able to create a profile and signing if they 1) own the email address and 2) verity the email

Comment: Signing out the user won't prevent the account from being created and in a state waiting for validation.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson - you're right. However, I purely want to prevent a user from signing up with a fraudulent email, just like every other application. Does that make sense? If I'm phrasing my ask incorrectly, let me know, but the process of "verifying an email account before allowing sign-in" is not new...

Comment: If you need to stop the user from doing certain things before the account is validated, you can express that in security rules.  Otherwise, you can't prevent the account from being created with any string that they claim is an email address, and parses like an email address.  The account is essentially the "container" that tracks the state of the account and its validation.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you should do is sign out from your own application:

```
// for FIRAuth
try? Auth.auth()?.signOut()

// for GoogleSignIn
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
```

The safari part is handled by the system and you don't need to worry about.